# Airflow 2.6.2 /tmp folder keeps getting very large

Tags: linux, docker-compose, airflow

Since I've updated to Airflow 2.6.2 the /tmp folder inside the Docker-Compose keeps getting very large.
I have to delete it manually to keep Airflow running.
What could be the root cause? How can I fix this?

Deleted the /tmp folder inside the airflow docker-compose manually.

Comment: Any process exiting without cleaning up after itself can bloat your /tmp folder. Do you know whether these are being created by Airflow itself, or by some of the Python code in individual workflows?